# Python pdfkit How to remove bookmarks and set margins

Tags: python, pdfkit

I am trying out pdfkit in python. I am having troubles two things.

1. I would like absolutely no bookmarks in the pdf.
2. I can not get the margins to be the ones that I set. The results I am getting are really wide left and right margins.

below is my code

```
import pdfkit

path_wkhtmltopdf = r'C:/Program Files/path/to/wkhtmltopdf.exe'
config = pdfkit.configuration(wkhtmltopdf=path_wkhtmltopdf)

options = {'page-size': 'LETTER', 
    'margin-top': '24px',
    'margin-right': '2px',
    'margin-bottom': '24px',
    'margin-left': '2px'}

url = 'https://www.cal_info.ca.gov/mypath'
path_file = c:/myfile/save/path/webpage.pdf'
pdfkit.from_url(url, path_file, configuration=config, options=options)
```

Something I have not tried is updating to the latest wkhtmltopdf.exe file.

Answer (score 1):

1. `--no-outline` flag should remove bookmarks.
2. Try setting margins in mm, for example: `--margin-bottom 5mm --margin-left 5mm --margin-right 5mm --margin-top 5mm`.